# Cloudinary Video is loaded and started succesfully after first load but after refresh it's paused automatically

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

https://unpkg.com/cloudinary-video-player@1.8.0/dist/cld-video-player.min.js

I am using this script to load video from cloudinary .

what is script doing is that , it is getting my video content , wrapping inside the div and adding some class . on the first load , the classes are -> " vjs-playing vjs-has-started vjs-user-inactive"

but after refresh , video is loaded to dom but it's stopped .

and we have this classes -> "vjs-paused vjs-controls-disabled vjs-workinghover vjs-v7 vjs-user-active"

what should be reason?

Many thanks , in advance

Comment: Could you please share the code you have that initializes the Video Player? Also, does it reproduce on its own (i.e. in a standalone environment JSFiddle/Codesanbox etc) or only on your site's page?